# Restrict background data not working on android 4.2.2

Tags: updates, background-data

Since updating my Samsung tablet to Android 4.2.2 I can no longer see the option to restrict background data when I select data usage > app > view app settings. For most apps now the view app settings is now greyed out and cannot be selected. For those apps where it can be selected the restrict background data option has disappeared. 
As I am on a limited data plan with big penalties when I go over my allocation I really need to restrict background data. Why has this option been removed and how can I overcome this problem?